# Syndication feeds and show I bother with providing anything other than RSS 2

Tags: cms

I'm creating a CMS and have lots of legacy code from other applications. I'm wondering should I bother providing other syndication formats except rss 2? I'm inclined to say no but was wondering what other peoples opinions were.

Answer (score 4):

I would say either RSS2 or Atom, pick one. Any modern reader should be able to handle either.